# Mercator map coordinates transformation formula

Tags: latitude-longitude, maps, xy, mercator

I have a third-party application with a city map of size `131072x131072`.

There are data on this map which contains x and y coordinates. I want to transform these coordinates to latitude and longitude. I know this map is some sort of Mercator projection but I don't know what exactly.

There is the distance coefficient:

`k=0.75990358305`

I've tried formulas from wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection) but with no success.

Can someone help to find out transformation formula?

Here are few coordinates which I know:

`(lat,lng) - (x,y)
(50.370186,30.458433) - (53655,86502)
(50.404793,30.613958) - (68149,81437)
(50.458076,30.604239) - (67240,73634)
(50.488285,30.526358) - (59988,69221)
(50.9333,29.903046) - (1920,3775)
(50.114937,31.281656) - (130375,123690)`

Comment: Do you know the coordinates of the corners of your map?

Comment: @FSimardGIS if you talking about x-y they are `(0, 0)` - `(131072, 131072)`

Comment: I meant their corresponding Latitude and Longitude.

Comment: @FSimardGIS `(0, 0) - (50.958968564,29.881995201)`, `(131072, 131072) - (50.092603202,31.242498527)`

Comment: I tried to map the coordinates using Mercator and an affine transformation. However, the residuals are 10-20 meters and somehow the coordinate of the lower right corner does not match at all with the rest. How accurate do you expect the data to be?

Comment: @FSimardGIS ~10m will be ok for me, coordinates (lat,lng) was calculated using this third-party application so I think they are not accurate. Also, I found variables `OFFX=1212417` and `OFFY=753663`. Maybe they can help somehow.

Comment: I guess a translation and scale transformation, something like `Latitude = 2 * atan(exp((-1.195 * y + 6614004) / 6378137)) - pi / 2` and `Longitude = (1.195 * x + 3326492) / 6378137`, could work relatively well but would have to be tested and refined with more points ideally.

Comment: @FSimardGIS what are these numbers: `1.195`, `6614004`, `3326492`? Where did you take them?

Comment: These are scale factor, the y and the x translation respectively. I had to 'adjust' your data on the Mercator projection and took those numbers from that adjustment.

Comment: I have to say, I have no idea what they reference with their offset x and y, maybe it's an arbitrarily chosen point, or maybe they use a different projection, but that would be very hard to tell.

Comment: Have you considered asking the application developers about it? Is that a possibility for you? Maybe it could shed some light about how this can be done.

Comment: @FSimardGIS I don't know developers so I can't ask them. Looks like your formulas are good for me. Can you, please, create answer for this topic I will accept it. Also, please tell there how you did the adjustment because I have a few other maps.

Comment: Actually, I used ArcMap to 'Spatially Adjust' your data points on the map, and then took the translation and scale that ArcMap calculated. I will try to write a simplified, purely mathematical alternative that doesn't require ArcMap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible methodology for referencing your map points in Latitude and Longitude. 
I assumed a sphere-based Mercator Projection for simplicity.

First, calculate the scale factor by dividing the distance between two points in Mercator and their distance in your map (based on your map coordinates). Ideally choose two points far away from each other.

```
a = 6378137 (Equatorial radius)
Mercator_x = a * Longitude
Mercator_y = a * ln(tan(pi / 4 + Latitude / 2)
```

(calculate the above for both points)

```
Distance_Mercator = Sqrt((Mercator_x2 - Mercator_x1) ^ 2 + (Mercator_y2 - Mercator_y1) ^ 2)
Distance_Map = Sqrt((x2 - x1) ^ 2 + (y2 - y1) ^ 2)
Scale_factor = Distance_Mercator / Distance_Map
```

Then, calculate the Mercator coordinates of the origin point (0,0) from its LatLon:

```
Mercator_x0 = a * Longitude_origin
Mercator_y0 = a * ln(tan(pi / 4 + Latitude_origin / 2)
```

Plug these values in the Mercator inverse formulas to calculate the LatLon of any point:

```
Latitude = 2 * atan(exp((Scale_factor * -y + Mercator_y0) / a)) - pi / 2
Longitude = (Scale_factor * x + Mercator_x0) / a
```

The accuracy of the results can also depend on the quality and accuracy of the data in your application. With your example points it seems good within a few tens of meters.